# Is there a way to look at the raw logs of zeitgeist?

Tags: zeitgeist, privacy, logs

Zeitgeist logs your activity in Unity. Is there a way to look at the raw logs it creates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logs are stored in `~/.local/share/zeitgeist/activity.sqlite`. They are stored in an SQLite database, so you will need an SQLite database browser to view them.

Comment: I like SQLite Database Browser `sudo apt-get install sqlitebrowser`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Zeitgeist stores its data in sqlite. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) and my zeitgeist usage data is in

```
~/.local/share/zeitgeist
```

In order to access the raw logs, you'll need to know some SQL, which I'll leave up to you. However, if you have not installed [sqlite3](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sqlite3) [image: Install sqlite3], the command line interface for SQLite Version 3, then do so

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

Then, you may interogate the raw data as follows

```
[11:33:50 oyrm zeitgeist]$ pwd # Just to show where we are
/home/oyrm/.local/share/zeitgeist
[11:33:54 oyrm zeitgeist]$ sqlite3 -interactive activity.sqlite
SQLite version 3.7.9 2011-11-01 00:52:41
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .tables
actor            extensions_conf  mimetype         storage        
event            interpretation   payload          text           
event_view       manifestation    schema_version   uri            
sqlite>
```

As you can see, I have access to the activity.sqlite database at this point and may execute SQL to my hearts content. Now, figuring out how these are all related will be a puzzle for you, but you can use sqlite3 to determine useful things like db and table schemas.