# I have Privacy: Record activity ON but how to view log and all the stuff?

Tags: 12.04, log, history, privacy

Where can I find the recorded data and screen snaps and etc things ?
I had tried to find them within :

```
 ~/.local/share/zeitgeist
```

directory but there are the following files available and i don't know how to work with them to show all recorded data and history.

```
activity.sqlite
activity.sqlite-shm
activity.sqlite-wal
fts.index
```

Help me how to open and view the log.

BTW Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, your question was asked earlier here on Askubuntu. Please check   this [Privacy: Record Activity ON?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/147009/privacy-record-activity-on) question. Apparently, you need a tool like `gnome-activity-journal` just as @Sylvain Pineau pointed out and it is **not** recommended to view these SQLite database files manually as there are high chances that we might accidentally modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can browse the recorded data using the `gnome-activity-journal` tool.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-activity-journal
```

[image]

From the command line, AFAIK there's no friendly tool to extract such data, but you can use the API, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015132/zeitgeist-command-line-query-client) on SO.

Comment: Ohk and thanks dear @Sylvain Pineau but here I don't want to install any additional softwares or tools,Is it possible ?

Comment: If you have sqlite3 already installed, you could use the method described is this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/171613/32239)